# How to find all user list in Accurev? Is the there any API or CLI for fetching all user of SCM Accurev?

Tags: version-control, devops, accurev, devops-services

How to find all user list in Accurev? Is the there any API or CLI for fetching all user of Version control Accurev?

I am trying to track all the user in tool.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to list users in AccuRev.

accurev show users